# Forcepoint Content Gateway is added to the Forcepoint Manger Server on Centos Environment

Tags: websense

I've deployed the Forcepoint Content Gateway on CentOS 7 within Nutanix. Currently, I'm encountering an issue when adding the Forcepoint Content Gateway to the FSM. The problem is "The Policy Server cannot be added. Policy Server or the Control Service, used to determine the Policy Server version, is not running. ".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAt3c.png)

Additionally, telnet to port 55806 is not working. I've already attempted to restart the Content Gateway service using './WCGAdmin restart,' but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue.
I would appreciate your guidance on how to start the Policy Server service via CentOS. Is it even possible to have the Content Gateway deployed in a CentOS environment? If so, could you please provide the relevant CLI commands that work on CentOS for troubleshooting?
Can I open the Content Gateway CLI on a CentOS environment?
Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `lsof -i :port` can help to see if it is running there and on what it is listening to